# How to set Keepalive on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcp, winsock, keep-alive

I have win32 application in which winsock is used for TCP/IP communication.
I am setting keepalive value with WSAIoctl function and it is **working** normally with windows XP.

But on Win. Server 2008 WSAIoctl fails, and WSAGetLastError returns 10022(invalid arguments) which does not make any sense.

My code which sets keepalive is follows;

```
// set per-connection keep-alive option 
tcp_keepalive keepAliveSettings; 
keepAliveSettings.onoff = 1; 
keepAliveSettings.keepalivetime = 500; 
eepAliveSettings.keepaliveinterval = 25;
```

int lastError = WSAIoctl(m_soc.chns[0], SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &keepAliveSettings, sizeof(keepAliveSettings), NULL, 0, &BytesReturned, NULL, NULL);
          if(lastError == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    lastError = WSAGetLastError();
                    Logger::Error("Setting keepalive failed ErrCode %d\n",lastError); }

EDIT:

I found the solution, maybe it can help someone else who faced same problem. I was trying to set keepalive just after the async. connect call, but now I am setting after completion of connect call and this solved the issue.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470551(v=VS.85).aspx

> On Windows Vista and later, the
>   SO_KEEPALIVE socket option can only be
>   set using the setsockopt function when
>   the socket is in a well-known state
>   not a transitional state. For TCP, the
>   SO_KEEPALIVE socket option should be
>   set either before the connect function
>   (connect, ConnectEx, WSAConnect,
>   WSAConnectByList, or WSAConnectByName)
>   is called, or after the connection
>   request is actually completed. If the
>   connect function was called
>   asynchronously, then this requires
>   waiting for the connection completion
>   before trying to set the SO_KEEPALIVE
>   socket option. If an application
>   attempts to set the SO_KEEPALIVE
>   socket option when a connection
>   request is still in process, the
>   setsockopt function will fail and
>   return WSAEINVAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, maybe it can help someone else who faced same problem.
I was trying to set keepalive just after the async. connect call, but now I am setting after completion of connect call and this solved the issue.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470551(v=VS.85).aspx

> On Windows Vista and later, the
>   SO_KEEPALIVE socket option can only be
>   set using the setsockopt function when
>   the socket is in a well-known state
>   not a transitional state. For TCP, the
>   SO_KEEPALIVE socket option should be
>   set either before the connect function
>   (connect, ConnectEx, WSAConnect,
>   WSAConnectByList, or WSAConnectByName)
>   is called, or after the connection
>   request is actually completed. If the
>   connect function was called
>   asynchronously, then this requires
>   waiting for the connection completion
>   before trying to set the SO_KEEPALIVE
>   socket option. If an application
>   attempts to set the SO_KEEPALIVE
>   socket option when a connection
>   request is still in process, the
>   setsockopt function will fail and
>   return WSAEINVAL.

Comment: An advice: Dont answer your own question. In case you found the answer then edit your question and mention the answer.

Comment: FYI, Stackoverflow allows you to answer your own question after two days.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the kernel is objecting to your choices of values. I would. You can't seriously want to set the keep-alive interval to 25ms. That is a completely insane value. The default value is two hours, and there is no point in setting it lower than several minutes. Similarly the keepalivetime should be set to half an hour or so, certainly not half a second.

Comment: Hello EJP, default keepaliveinterval is not 2 hours. But default keepalivetime is 2 hours, and default keepaliveinterval is 1000 ms.
I know these values are insane for normal network applications but this application is running on LAN, so they are doing quite well. 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782936(WS.10).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758083(WS.10).aspx

Comment: The default interval between keep alive probes is 2 hours. This is mandated in the RFC. An interval of a second or less is insane, LAN or no LAN. If they're doing quite well what exactly is the problem?